# Need Help with Keyboard Macros

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, macros

Does anyone know a good program in which I could write a macro? I need it to check for updates on the screen (ie. notification coming up) and then do a certain task based off of what that notification would be. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There are dozens of tools that fit your requirements. Please try a few ones, and if they don't satisfy you and you come to understand your own requirements better, please edit then ask us to reopen. Thanks and good luck! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple tools to accomplish that such as:

[AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)

[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)

Both of them have a lot of functions and features make sure that you read the docs.

Comment: When a question is so broad that there are dozens of possible answers, please flag the question so that we can have a look, it will make you save time. Thanks a lot for participating! :-)

Comment: Of the two, I much prefer AutoIt (+1)